# php echo without having to escape quotes

Tags: php, syntax, escaping, echo

Is there a way to 'echo' / 'render HTML' and not have to escape every quote?

Kind of like how below the HTML below is being rendered without having to use `echo` or escape anything.

*disregard any php syntax errors, example only*

```
 <? if($a == $b) {;?> I said: "It's with quotes" <? ;} ?>
 <? else {;?> They said "It's still with quotes" <? ;} ?>
```

the reason for this is I need to echo a large Javascript file that uses both single and double quotes, and it would take forever to escape them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're just trying to *display* (not run) some code, you can use any of these two approaches:

- Store the JavaScript file as a separate file, and use `file_get_contents()` to get the code and display it in `<pre>` code-blocks
- Use the [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax to store the file contents

**Approach #1:**

```
$contents = file_get_contents('file.js');
echo '<pre>', $contents, '</pre>';
```

**Approach #2:**

```
$contents = <<<FILE

... contents ...

FILE;

echo '<pre>', $contents, '</pre>';
```

---

I'd go with the first approach though. That way, you won't clutter up your script with long JavaScript code that's not actually used for page rendering. It's usually a good idea to separate your logic into multiple files. In both cases though, you don't have to worry about quoting, at all.

Comment: There is file I/O involved in the first approach. It's akin to loading the data from any data source. I'm not saying it's bad. It just seems like the OP was looking for away to write some inline text without having to escape quotes.

Comment: @crush: There's no input. You're just reading the file - nothing more.  The correct answer to the OP's problem would be "Use HEREDOC / NOWDOC", but I just wanted to provide an alternative way to avoid the code from becoming hard to maintain.

Comment: I'm just saying there is overhead involved in the reading of the file. That's all I was saying. I wasn't trying to cast judgment.

Comment: @crush: I understand and I agree with on that. Please tell me which one would you prefer? 1) Script (say 200 lines) that fetches the the contents to be displayed from a *different* file, or 2) Script (say 1200 lines) that contains the whole JavaScript file stored as a *string* that is **cluttered** and **not maintainable**? I don't think the slight performance loss from storing the file as a different file should matter, however that's for the OP to decide :)

Comment: If it's a large block of content, then it undeniably belongs in some form of an external data source. Absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

```
$str = <<<TEXT
I said: "It's with quotes"
TEXT;
```

The `TEXT` can be anything, as long as you use it on the opening line and the closing line:

```
$str = <<<ANYTHING
I said: "It's with quotes"
ANYTHING;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the so-called [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (pronounce here doc).

Here is an example:

```
$js = <<<JAVASCRIPT
var some = {
    "javascript": 'here'
};
JAVASCRIPT;
```

You don't need to escape anything, because you define named delimiters. In this case the delimiter is `JAVASCRIPT`. I suggest you read the whole documentation page and choose the best for your case. For example PHP 5.3+ provides the nice [`nowdoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax.

Comment: @crush I used to call it `he-re-doc`. I thought it was an acronym or something. One day it just punched me in the face.

Comment: I think the downvote must be from the fact that you can't use HEREDOC like that with `echo`. You need to store it in a variable first.

Comment: @crush you *can* actually echo a heredoc string (see example #2 from the linked PHP manual).

Comment: nooooo @HaralanDobrev I think you were right befooooorrreee!

Comment: @admdrew It's always better to have a variable here instead of just echo-ing a literal.

Comment: I realize the documentation shows that example, [but it doesn't work in this ideone.com example.](http://ideone.com/taTvNV)

Comment: Ah! Ok. (thiscommentisn'tlongenough)

Comment: @crush You need an empty line at the end.

Comment: I see that is buried in the Warning message now after closer reading: *"The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline."*

Answer (score -1):

You can use the opposite type of quotes to delimit your strings:

```
echo "It's with quotes";
echo 'He said "Do it!"';
```

You only have to escape quotes if they're the same as the ones used to delimit the string. So if you have both types of quotes in your string, you'll need to escape some of them:

```
echo 'They said "It\'s still with quotes"';
```

Another solution, usually used for long blocks, is *heredoc*:

```
echo <<<EOF
They said "It's still with quotes"
EOF;
```

Comment: Both types of quotes are used. It's a mash-up of different scripts.

Comment: You can mix and match as much as you like.

Comment: It sounds like the OP does not want to `escape some of them`. [Amal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21706765/1454048) is probably better at this point (and he was the first to reference heredoc).